# Magnetism problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I encountered a magnetism problem requiring me to find out the minimum velocity (along $\hat{\mathbf{i}}$) given to a charged particle so that it passes through the centre of a circular region of radius $r$ (on XY plane) where magnetic field is present along -$\hat{\mathbf{k}}$. Electric field is absent and all required quantities are known. Note that $\theta$ is the angle made by initial velocity vector of the particle before entering the region and the radius vector.

So the basic equation that I'll need here is $R=\frac{mv}{qB}$ (not deriving it) where $R$ is the radius of the circle along which the particle will move while other quantities have their usual meaning.
My problem is with calculating the value of $R$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.

I tried converting the given situation to a cartesian system and getting three points to find the equation of the circle of radius $R$ but couldn't get the third point. I also tried a trigonometric approach which didn't yield anything either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

Draw two intersecting circles (A and B), ( of different sizes r and R), with B passing through the center of  A. Construct an isosceles triangle, center of A to center of B, and radii from each center to the point intersection. Remember that an arc of B is perpendicular to its radius at that point. After splitting your triangle into two right triangles, you can show that the sine of your given angle is r/(2R).